# Icon for notification in a Mac Qt C++ application

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt, nsnotificationcenter

With a Qt C++ application, I am using some objective-c code to display notifications on Mac, which works as expected.

Although, the icon is defined in my plist file and is properly displayed in the dock, the icon in the notification itself or in the notification settings (in System Preferences) is the default grey one.

Here is what I have used in the objective-c code:

`notification.contentImage = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSApplicationIcon"] retain];`

What should I do to have the icon correctly displayed in the notification?